# SwfitUI creating a function that acts like a @published variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a class which has two published variables:

```
class Controller: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myArray: Array<Int>: [1,2,3,4,5]
    @Published var currIndex: Int = 0


    func currItem() -> Int {
        return myArray[curIndex]
    }
}
```

I want my view to subscribe to the function "currItem" instead of the currIndex variable
Is there an elegant way to achieve it?
without subscribing to the function I need to write some boilerplate code:

```
struct myView: View {
    var controller: Controller = Controller()
    var body: some View {
        Text(controller.myArray[controller.currIndex]) // <-- Replace this with controller.currItem()        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it even much better than that, like this:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var controller: Controller = Controller()
    
    var body: some View {

        Text(controller.currItem?.description ?? "Error!")

    }
}
```

---

```
class Controller: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var myArray: Array<Int> =  [1,2,3,4,5]
    @Published var currIndex: Int? = 0
    
    var currItem: Int? {
        
        get {
            
            if let unwrappedIndex: Int = currIndex {
                
                if myArray.indices.contains(unwrappedIndex) {

                    return myArray[unwrappedIndex]

                }
                else {

                    print("Error! there is no such index found!")
                    return nil

                }
                
            }
            else {
                
                print("Error! you did not provide a value for currIndex!")
                return nil
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answers. I have a question, why did you use "State" instead of "StateObject" for the controller variable?

Comment: Sorry Kevin that was my typing problem, it should be StateObject, thanks